# JSON of ObjectA contenent a List<ObjectB>

Tags: java, android, json, string, list

I must convert to JSon String my Object.

I have a class (ObjectA)

```
public class ObjectA {
    private int information;
    private List<ObjectB> objB;
}
```

And this class (JSon) try to solve my problem

```
    public class JSon extends Activity {

    private ObjectA objA;

    public JSon() { }

    Public String toJSON(Object pObject) {
            this.objA = pObject;
            String temp = "";

            JSONObject jsonObject= new JSONObject();
            try {
                jsonObject.put("information", objA.getInfo());
                for (int i=0; i<objA.getobjB().size(); i++) {
                   temp = this.objBToJSON(i);
                   jsonObject.put("objB", temp);
                }

                return jsonObject.toString();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "";
       }

       private String objBToJSON(int i) {
           JSONObject jsonObject= new JSONObject();
           try {
              jsonObject.put("info1", objAI.getobjB().get(i).getInfo1());
              jsonObject.put("info2", objAI.getobjB().get(i).getInfo2());

              return jsonObject.toString();
           } catch (JSONException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
           return "";
        }
   }

     public ObjectA toOkjectA(String pString) {

       ObjectA objA = new Gson().fromJson(pString, ObjectA.class);
       return objA;
}
```

}

The toJSON method (called in another class, String temp = new JSon().toJSON(objA) ) don't save correctly my Obj, because when i try to read it (objA = new Gson().fromJson(pStringJSON, Libretto.class)) i have an error (Expected BEGIN_ARRAY). So, how can i resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

Make your life easy and use a predefined library to handle this for you. I recommend Jackson.
http://jackson.codehaus.org/1.0.0/javadoc/org/codehaus/jackson/map/ObjectMapper.html

Comment: Great! Thank you, i'm tryng Jackson library. But i have a question? i must assign the JSon String of my Object at an specific variable. How can i do it? What method of ObjectMapper i must use?

Answer (score 0):

I see you are using Gson. Good choice :)

JSONObject can handle

```
{
  "array": [
    {
      "key": "value1"
    },
    {
      "key": "value2"
    }
  ]
}
```

JSONObject can not handle

```
[
  {
    "key": "value1"
  },
  {
    "key": "value2"
  }
]
```

To solve this, instead of using JSONObject, use **JSONElement**. It can handle both.

Comment: Thank you!! So, here is my problem. But, as suggested below, i would try Jackson library to solve it and semplify my code :)